# In installing there is a problem in Linux Mint. How I can solve this problem?

Tags: installation, linux-mint

Selecting previously unselected package libpng12-0:amd64.
dpkg: regarding libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb containing libpng12-0:amd64, pre-dependency problem:
libpng12-0 pre-depends on multiarch-support
multiarch-support is not installed.

dpkg: error processing archive libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb (--install):
pre-dependency problem - not installing libpng12-0:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
libpng12-0_1.2.50-2+deb8u3_amd64.deb

Comment: Are you trying a fresh new mint installation?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question might be better suited for [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Check it:

- Did you check if your ISO file is OK, maybe it's corrupted? Verify it https://linuxmint.com/verify.php
- Is your computer 32bit or 64bit? Maybe it is the problem. If your computer is 32bits try Linux Mint 19.2 "Tina" - Cinnamon (32-bit) https://www.linuxmint.com/edition.php?id=268
- Did you downloaded de last stable version?

Comment: my computer is 64bit. Cinnamon version is 4.6.6

Comment: Did you try MATE or Xfce?

Comment: I didn't try it.